# I keep getting the BSOD. how do I trace what application / driver is causing it?

Tags: windows-vista, bsod, x86

I get a **APC_INDEX_MISMATCH** error and it says it is dumping memory.

Where is the dump sent? 
More importantly how do i scan it to find out who is causing the BSOD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually the dumps are saved to %systemroot/minidump  - MS has documentation on that [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263). You can view and analyse these with [whocrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed) (which is simpler, and does most of the analysis for you) or [bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) (which lets you see the actual dump, or load dumps from other systems, but dosen't do any interpretation - it just lets you google up the errors).

Comment: Wish I'd known about those tools in the past, great find, bookmarked!

Answer (score 1):

you could check "c:\windows\MEMORY.DMP" or "c:\windows\Minidump" is or not exist,if exist and open file with "Debugging Tools for Windows what this edition of the Debugging Tools for Windows documentation describes four Microsoft debuggers" and then check error detail information