# The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck

Tags: windows-8, troubleshooting, bsod

My Windows 8 computer frequently locks up when you try to wake it up from sleep. The power light appears on, but the monitor shows no connection and it won't 'wake up'. I have to hold the power button to turn it off and reset it. I found this in the event log. I don't know if it crashed before I tried to wake it, or if it locks up the moment I press a key. The previous error is 8:40am. How would I debug it to find out the source of the problem?

It is a Dell XPS 8500. I've already run the Dell BIOS hardware tests, including memory tests, with the 'extended test' option, overnight, and it found no problem.

```
Error   8/8/2013 1:18:34 PM EventLog    6008    None

The previous system shutdown at 12:02:22 PM on ‎8/‎8/‎2013 was unexpected.

Error   8/8/2013 1:18:40 PM BugCheck    1001    None

Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WER-SystemErrorReporting
Date:          8/8/2013 1:18:40 PM
Event ID:      1001
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      xps
Description:
The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000003b (0x00000000c0000005, 0xfffff88001d01e0f, 0xfffff8801e33a8b0, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in: C:\windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 080813-32203-01.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WER-SystemErrorReporting" Guid="{ABCE23E7-DE45-4366-8631-84FA6C525952}" EventSourceName="BugCheck" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">1001</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-08-08T17:18:40.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>9844</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>xps</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">0x0000003b (0x00000000c0000005, 0xfffff88001d01e0f, 0xfffff8801e33a8b0, 0x0000000000000000)</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">C:\windows\MEMORY.DMP</Data>
    <Data Name="param3">080813-32203-01</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I ran both WhoCrashed and BlueScreenView. I have 15 minidumps. WhoCrashed always reported ndis.sys (except 1) and eventually concluded mfehidk01.sys (McAfee) was the problem. Here is a copy of the WhoCrashed report: https://community.mcafee.com/message/298870#298870

BlueScreenView nearly always reported ndis.sys (just 3 were not). Here is one row.

```
080813-32203-01.dmp 8/8/2013 12:03:04 PM    SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION    0x0000003b  00000000`c0000005   fffff880`01d01e0f   fffff880`1e33a8b0   00000000`00000000   ndis.sys    ndis.sys+aee0f                  x64 ntoskrnl.exe+5a440                  C:\windows\Minidump\080813-32203-01.dmp 8   15  9200    280,384 8/8/2013 1:18:40 PM
```

Here is the full report from BlueScreenView: https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/6190566

ndis.sys is from Microsoft, so what can I do?

Comment: zip and uplaod the file **C:\windows\MEMORY.DMP** to SkyDrive/dropbox and pst a link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 These are pretty frequent. I might want to learn how to analyze them myself. I tried WhoCrashed and BlueScreenView and added to the question.

Comment: watch this video: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks . And forget WhoCrashed or BlueScreenView, they teoll you 99% the wrong thing.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks! I installed it and tried it out and watched the video, but it complained about missing symbols. Seems a bit of a pain to set it all up. Definitely not trivial.

Comment: configure the symbols correctly: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us

Comment: Had the exact same problem, on a Dell XPS as well (Dell XPS 8500)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start debugging:

- Google the given error code (0x0000003b) to determine the nature of the failure.
- Examine the MEMORY.DMP it made to try and find out the culprit.

For more information on examining Memory Dump files see this SU question and its answers:

[I keep getting the BSOD. how do I trace what application / driver is causing it?](https://superuser.com/questions/437057/i-keep-getting-the-bsod-how-do-i-trace-what-application-driver-is-causing-it/437064#437064)

Also, basic overnight memory tests are OK, but you're better off using something like [Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) and letting it run for 2 or 3 *DAYS* before deciding the RAM is OK.

Additionally, you may want to take a look at this similar question, as they ran into a similar Bug check code with Windows 8:

[How to get more info out of the uninformative Windows 8 BSOD?](https://superuser.com/questions/492422/how-to-get-more-info-out-of-the-uninformative-windows-8-bsod)

Comment: Thanks. I ran WhoCrashed and BlueScreenView and they both reported ndis.sys, by Microsoft. WhoCrashed eventually blamed McAfee, but I don't know how it came to that conclusion. I added to the question.

Comment: I uninstalled McAfee, rebooted, and turned on Windows Defender and so far no crashes (1 day only). I also ran Memtest86+ all night and it went through 5 passes without a problem. I installed WinDbg and loaded some of the dump files but it complained I didn't have the symbols. It's a bit of a pain to set up.

Comment: It still crashes about once a week. Either ndis.sys or ntdll.sys.